# az ml workspace share command (v1) alternatives

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-service-principal

I'm trying to share my azure ML workspace by SP (Service Principal)

I've created a SP and share my workspace to the SP

But when I try to share a workspace using the cli, I get this error:

`'share' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.`

Maybe I guess this error was caused by version of azure cli, (share command only exists in v1 docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ml(v1)/workspace?view=azure-cli-latest)

I also searched azure-cli v2 documentation and commands (`az ml workspace`), but I don't have any idea to alter the command above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are working on V2 and you want to do workspace sharing, but there are some changes between CLI V1 and V2.

To migrate from Azure Machine Learning V1 to V2, you need to upgrade **az ml workspace share** commands to equivalent **az role assignment create** commands.

Please refer to here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-role-assignment-create
Create a new role assignment for a user, group, or service principal.

```
az role assignment create --role
                          [--assignee]
                          [--assignee-object-id]
                          [--assignee-principal-type {ForeignGroup, Group, ServicePrincipal, User}]
                          [--condition]
                          [--condition-version]
                          [--description]
                          [--name]
                          [--resource-group]
                          [--scope]
```

There are some examples for how to use it here for your reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-role-assignment-create-examples

I hope this helps!